# Login in app using Web-Server

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone-8 app In this I need to register e-mail and password and after I have to login with registered user-name and password.I am using HttpWebRequest Class but don't know how it is possible please share with me any info or link regarding that.

Comment: What problem is stopping you? You do not know how to work with HttpWebRequest or what?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a separate web server running an auth service. Instead, you could use [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/). There are several reasons for that, the main being the fact that you can easily manage outgoing data (register users) and check for existing data (authenticating users).

You can use the [Azure Mobile Services client](https://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/0.2.0) if you need an abstracted out data access layer.